# Benchmarking Multi-threaded Collections in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java.util.concurrent, jmh

I'm using JMH to measure average-time spent in Collections.

As I was trying to achieve multithreaded `add`, `get` and `remove` I wanted to be sure that the operations are correctly written to use such structures.

I'll describe the idea for removing in lists.

1. `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Double>(collection)`
2. `Collections.synchronizedList(collection)`

Benchmarks look like this:

```java
@Benchmark
public List<Double> testRemoveWithIndex(Data d, Blackhole blackhole) {
   List<Double> obj = d.getCollection();
   ParallelBenchmarkListsRemove.removeRandomInList(d.getCollection(), d.orderArray, d.objects, blackhole);
    return obj;
}
```

With the `removeRandomInList` method:

```java
public static <T> void removeRandomInList(List<T> filledList, int[] order, int noObjects, Blackhole blackhole) {
    while (filledList.size() > 1) {
        blackhole.consume(filledList.remove(order[noObjects - filledList.size()]));
    }
}
```

Similar situation is in `add` and `get`. Each of the operations have its data structure that specifies the collection that is returned, order in which it should remove elements and number of objects added into collection.

For `add` operation:

```java
public static <T> void fillList(List<T> listToFill, T[] fillingArray, int noObjects) {
    int i = 0;
    while (listToFill.size() < noObjects) {
        listToFill.add(fillingArray[i++]);
    }
}
```

And for `get` operation:

```java
public static <T> void getRandomFromList(List<T> filledList, int[] order, int noObjects, Blackhole blackhole) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i * 10 < noObjects) {
        blackhole.consume(filledList.get(order[i++]));
    }
}
```

Is this approach correct for different number of threads (1, 8, 64)?

Comment: What is the question? Did you try it? What happened?  Do the results look bogus?

Comment: @JimGarrison Well I tried it and it runs for like 15 hours (quite a lot of tasks), but I don't know what results should I await, and mainly as I'm not experienced I wanted the approval or advice if these whiles are okey in multithreaded processing

Comment: When writing questions, please be sure to include all relevant information.  The fact that it has run 15 hours is surely relevant.

Comment: If it runs for that long, maybe you should "test the test" by running it on a smaller set of data, or fewer iterations of benchmarking. Once the test is what you want it to be, you run it on full.

Comment: @Andreas It technically is not.. I have multiple object sizes (1, 100, 1000, 10000) and I run it with Double and MyObject data types and as I wrote different threadpool sizes (1, 8, 64) and with 10 warmup and 20 iterations and forking 2 times it is irrelevant

Comment: You have an infinite loop in the Get section right?  Did you want `i++`?   You really should be using for loops exactly for this reason so you make sure you have the init, test, increment portions.

Comment: @Gray oh, thanks, have forgotten about this one. All operations are fishy, although they somehow work. But I just cannot find the way to make parallel reads/writes for jmh to be measured correctly :/